# Push a view on top of a SplitViewController on launch

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a SplitViewController for my iPad application and I want to push a screen on top of it when it launches  so I can have a login screen. The problem is that I have not been able to get a screen to hide the main and detail screen.

I can not use addsubview since the rootview is not hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do this simple thing, make loginview controller rootview controller 
In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: make

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController
```

and on successful login make your splitviewcontroller root view controller

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splitViewController
```

Comment: This is brilliantly simple, and seems to work great. Is there any downside to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this type of thing you would have to create your own implementation of a SplitViewController. One popular implementation is [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).

Comment: I've had trouble getting presentModalViewController to work well on top of a UISplitViewController. Do you have a more complete example that shows this working in a way which handles screen rotation properly?